# Multiple Insert with dropdown codeigntier

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have3 table with name frm_data_aset,frm_monitor,frm_lokasi
I want if I insert on frm_data_aset column monitor_aset with dropdown from tabel monitor and lokasi from tabel lokasi. on table monitor column lokasi updated with data same at I insert from tabel data_Aset 
this my structure :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSr35.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eTc4.jpg)

> now I get error :
>   Unknown column 'frm_monitor' in 'where clause'
>   UPDATE `frm_monitor` SET `lokasi_monitor` = '123' WHERE `frm_monitor` IS NULL

this my controller :

```
{
    $this->_rules();
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->create();
    } else {
        $data = array(
    'lokasi_aset' => $this->input->post('lokasi_aset',TRUE),
    'monitor_aset' => $this->input->post('monitor_aset',TRUE),
    );
        $id= $this->input->post('kd_monitor', TRUE);
        $data = array(
        'lokasi_monitor' => $this->input->post('lokasi_aset'),
    );
        $this->M_monitor->update_lokasi($id,$data);
        $this->M_data_aset->insert($data);
        redirect(site_url('data_aset'));
    }
}
```

this my model M_monitor

```
function update_lokasi($id,$data){
$this->db->where('frm_monitor', $id);
$this->db->update('frm_monitor', $data);
}
```

and this my dropdown monitor at form insert data_aset

```
<option value="0">Pilih Monitor</option>
            <?php
                $monitor = $this->db->get('frm_monitor')->result();
                foreach ($monitor as $row){
                echo "<option value='$row->kd_monitor' ";
                echo $row->kd_monitor==$monitor_aset?'selected':'';
                echo ">".  strtoupper($row->kd_monitor)."</option>";
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: can you get the table structure

Comment: I only can show the link above, but must 10 reputation to show image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rename the `$data` variable being passed to `$this->M_monitor->update_lokasi()` because it will overwrite `$data` that is going to be passed to `$this->M_data_aset->insert()` with only `'lokasi_monitor'` array on it. Or even better try rename both `$data` to prevent confusion.

Modify your controller :

```
{
    $this->_rules();
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->create();
    } else {
        $data_aset = array(
            'lokasi_aset' => $this->input->post('lokasi_aset',TRUE),
            'monitor_aset' => $this->input->post('monitor_aset',TRUE),
        );
        $id = $this->input->post('kd_monitor', TRUE);
        $data_monitor = array(
            'lokasi_monitor' => $this->input->post('lokasi_aset'),
        );
        $this->M_monitor->update_lokasi($id,$data_monitor);
        $this->M_data_aset->insert($data_aset);
        redirect(site_url('data_aset'));
    }
}
```

And change `'frm_monitor'` to `'kd_monitor'` on the conditional query :

```
function update_lokasi($id,$data){
    $this->db->where('kd_monitor', $id);
    $this->db->update('frm_monitor', $data);
}
```

Comment: Awesome It Works, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try changing your model query as like this

```
    function update_lokasi($id,$data){
$this->db->where('id_monitor', $id);
$this->db->update('frm_monitor', $data);
}
```

Before that make sure that the post for 'kd_monitor' in the controller is not null

Comment: Unknown column 'id_aset' in 'where clause'
UPDATE `frm_monitor` SET `lokasi_monitor` = '123' WHERE `id_aset` IS NULL
Can't find 'id_aset' bro, because I write this model om M_monitor

Comment: i think your id value is null